# Should I move system messages to a config file?

Tags: c#, silverlight

I'm working on a Silverlight application that makes calls to WCF web services for certain data retrievals. Occasionally I have to display messages to the user if their login credentials are incorrect, account is locked, if their session has expired etc. Is it okay having the message language within C# code,

```
if (SessionHasExpired(username))
{
    result.Message = "Your session has expired, please login again.";
}
```

or is it a better practice to move the message language to a config file, so it can be more easily changed?

Comment: Why not use resources as normal applications?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best practice is to put your strings in a [resources file](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7k989cfy%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) that way if you ever decide to [support multiple languages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s9ckwb4b%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) you just need to use the satellite assembly for whatever language you have selected.

Comment: Also, for a quick reference you can follow this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3461280/what-is-the-best-way-to-associate-error-messages-with-error-codes-in-c. Just replace codes with your message numbers